# Como converter coordenadas de tela para coordenadas cartesianas?

Tags: javascript, python, coordenadas, geometria

Em Python:
Como converter coordenadas da tela para coordenadas cartesianas, onde podem haver pontos positivos e negativos e o centro da tela é (0,0)?

Comment: gostaria de saber se você testou minha solução.

Comment: deu certinho cara, valeu!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este é um problema de conversão de sistema de coordenadas e considerando que a sua linguagem de programação tem como origem (0, 0) o canto superior esquerdo da tela temos (em JavaScript - em Python é análogo) :

```
<div style="width: 600px; height: 300px; border: 1px #000 solid; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">


var larguraTela = 600;
var alturaTela = 300;
var getXY = function(x, y) {
    var novoX =  x - (larguraTela / 2);
    var novoY = (y - (alturaTela / 2)) * -1;
    return [ novoX, novoY ];
}

document.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    console.log(evt.x + ", " + evt.y);
    console.log(getXY(evt.x, evt.y));
}, false);
```

Fiz em javaScript / HTML para testar no browser dando cliques no retangulo e observando a console do browser, mas o que importa é a função getXY() que espera como parâmetro a coordenada X e Y originais e retorna um array de dois elementos: x e y convertidos.

Observe que é necessário multiplicar por (-1) em Y devido a **direção inversa** em relação ao **sistema cartesiano** tradicional.